# Django BDD testing with aloe, get absolute URL

Tags: python, django, lettuce

I'm doing BDD testing with [Django-Aloe](https://github.com/koterpillar/aloe_django/),
To make things fast the tests runs in threads and for each thread there is a different port.

I can't seem to find a way to access the absolute URL.

in lettuce I had this:

```
from lettuce.django import django_url
world.browser.visit(django_url('home'))
```

Which would translate to `http://localhost:8090/home/` as described [here](http://lettuce.it/recipes/django-lxml.html#lettuce-figure-out-django-urls).

Now in aloe what can i do in this test step to get to the absolute url?

```
@step(r'I access the url "(.*)"')
def access_url(step, url):
    world.browser.visit(?????)
```

Answer (score 1):

I opened a ticket on github and apparently it was added to the latest release, after closing my ticket they added it to the [docs](https://aloe.readthedocs.org/projects/aloe-django/en/latest/#aloe_django.django_url)